# Can I do a subtree merge from a subdirectory?

Tags: git, git-subtree

Let's assume two git repositories with some files in them:

```
ProjectA
+ a
+ b

ProjectB
+ foo/x
+ foo/y
+ bar/z
```

Now I want to include the directory `foo` from *ProjectB* into *ProjectA*.

As far as I understand when I do `git subtree add` the `prefix` is the path that it should have in the receiving repository, so when I do

```
git subtree add --prefix=project_b --squash URL_of_ProjectB
```

I would end up with

```
ProjectA
+ a
+ b
+ project_b
  + foo/x
  + foo/y
  + bar/z
```

Can I somehow specifiy that I only want `foo` fetched to get this layout?

```
ProjectA
+ a
+ b
+ project_b
  + x
  + y
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this can't be accomplished with `git subtree`. Maybe `git filter-branch` is what you need:

```
git remote add b <URL_TO_B>
git fetch b
git checkout -b b_master b/master
```

Rewrite the history of `b` only containing `foo`:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter foo b_master
```

or use `git subtree split`

```
git subtree split -P foo --branch foo
```

and add it as as subtree

```
git subtree add --prefix=project_b --squash b_master or foo
```

Comment: Does this change the process of merging in further changes in ProjectB into ProjectA? I thought my scenario is exactly what `git subtree` is for, but if it's not, what *can* be accomplished with it? Maybe I can change my file layout to suit it better.

Comment: Yes, you have to redo the filter branch step every time you want to merge changes from ProjectB into ProjectA. The man page of `git subtree` explains the `git split` command which is similar to the `filter-branch` command I gave. But if you can change your layout maybe it's better to extract the conntent of `foo` into a seperate repository and add it as a subtree to both projects. Maybe this is better since `b` is some kind of lib?

Comment: That's the problem, it's not really. If it was, I would make it a submodule. It's rather some code that is shared among two projects... a list of countries, some templates, etc.

Comment: I opted to split off the subtree using `git subtree split` in the original repository, push the new branch and then fetch that branch into the receiving one using `git subtree add`. Thanks.

Comment: Is it also possible to merge back changes on extracted dir "foo" from ProjectA to ProjectB?